How to create and use glossary in text translation and document translation
I have implemented interface like DeepL to translate text and document. I have one auth key and I am using it in my application for translation, so many employees in my organization can take a benefit of this subscription.
Now I want to maintain a glossary for each user. How can I achieved this feature?

This is not possible. DeepL glossaries are shared with the entire account, see the documentation.

is there a way to achieve this with a single subscription?
